# errorclass, errorvalue when I try to add new model/table to existing database

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

When I try to add new model to SQLAlchemy I get error ( I am using MySQL below)

```
raise errorclass, errorvalue
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError 1005 Can't create table
```

I have model/table PlayerModel/players since beginning of the time and I am trying now to add new table (Base has id column id)

```
class Base(object):
    def __tablename__(self):
        return self.__name__.lower()

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
class PlayerModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'players'
    alliances_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('alliances.id'), nullable=True)
    alliance = relationship('AllianceModel')
    username = Column(String(90), nullable=True, default=None)
    email = Column(String(75), nullable=True, default=None)
    password = Column(String(128), nullable=True, default=None)
    money = Column(Integer, nullable=False, default=INITIAL_MONEY)
    # used for push notifications
    push_token = Column(String(64), nullable=True)
    registered_for_push = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    device_id = Column(String(64), nullable=True)
    device_type = Column(String(64), nullable=True)
    device_os = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    notify = Column(Boolean, default=True)


    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Player('%s')>" % (self.type)
```

and here throw error

```
class ArmyModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'army'

    player_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('players.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False, index=True)
    speed = Column(Float, nullable=False, default=1)
    # mode of army behavior ( always fight, ignore )
    mode = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    x = Column(Float, nullable=False, default=0)
    y = Column(Float, nullable=False, default=0)
    z = Column(Float, nullable=False, default=0)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Army('%s')>" % (self.type)
```

Comment: It looks like mysql thinks you've defined your `ForeignKey` relation incorrectly. Please, do 2 things: 1. log the actually `CREATE TABLE` query and include in the question; 2. remove `ondelete='CASCADE'` and see if it still throws an error. Thanks.